# Local Apache from Android via Connectify

Tags: wi-fi

I have the Apache web server running on my PC. I want to view pages on this server from my Android device which is connected to my PC via [Connectify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectify).

I believe this is possible because there's an Android app I'm using called Unified Remote and with this program I can manage the computer remotely. So this proves data communication between the PC and the Android device via Connectify is working.

This app connects to the PC using the IP address `192.168.2.1`. When I try the same IP address from the Android browser, it gets stuck at loading for a really long time with no response.

How do I fix this problem?

By the way, I'm using Android 2.2 (it's [CyanogenMod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CyanogenMod) 6, but I believe the browser is stuck).

I stopped Apache and installed another webserver called Abyss Web Server and now it works. So the problem IS Apache-specific. Which settings of Apache can prevent my Android device working over this network?

Comment: Do you have any other machines on your network? Can you connect to your Apache server from any of them? Have you checked the firewall settings on your PC, port 80 is normally blocked by default.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could  be a problem with your Apache configuration. Maybe the server isn't listening on the correct address? Check that the server is set to listen to all relevant IPs or all of them with a wildcard if necessary.

Comment: The related configuration is already `Listen 80` so i think it already accepts requests from all IPs over port 80.

Comment: If Connectify uses a virtual network adapter, is it always present with a valid IP or is it created when you start the hotspot? If it's the latter, try restarting Apache after Connectify is connected, so that Apache detects the new IP and listens to it. You can see the ports your pc listens by running `netstat -an`

Answer (score 0):

Best thing to do would be to check your Apache logs and see if you are indeed getting a HTTP request from your phone. If you seeing entries as requests from the phone then it could be an issue with the Apache setup. If you aren't getting any log entries then most likely the issue is from the device's side.

Comment: i checked the apache logs like you advised, and there's no sign of an android device, just my desktop browser. So, if the issue is from device's side what can it be?

Comment: @keune If you would like to troubleshoot Android connectivity to the Apache specifically I would recommend to start Apache in the forground with this command: `httpd -f <path to config file>` and make sure it is listening the correct configuration file is selected. Test Apache from another machine on the same network, then if that works, in theory, it should work from your android device. You could also try different browsers on the Android (Dolphin for example).